# How to properly add a custom field to User in WordPress Rest Api?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to add a custom updatable field to show in the User rest api.

I managed to show the field properly on GET requests but it's not updating with new values on POST requests.

This is the code i have on functions.php:

```
function slug_add_post_data() {
    register_rest_field('user',
        'ubicaciones',
        array(
            'get_callback' => 'slug_get_field',
            'update_callback' => 'slug_update_field',
            'schema' => array(
                                'description' => 'Ubicaciones usuario',
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'context' => array('view', 'edit')
                            )
        )
    );
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'slug_add_post_data');

function slug_get_field($user, $field_name, $request) {
  return get_user_meta($user->id, $field_name);
}

function slug_update_field($value, $user, $field_name) {
  if (!$value || !is_string($value)) {
    return;
  }

  return update_user_meta($user->ID, $field_name, strip_tags($value));
}
```

Something must be wrong with the update_callback function, but i can't find exactly what.

Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.
this post helped me: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293025/curl-post-work-with-user-meta-but-not-the-custom-user-meta

```
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {


    register_rest_field(
          "user"
        , "ubicaciones"
        ,
        [
            "get_callback" => function ($user, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {

                return get_user_meta($user["id"], $field_name, TRUE);

            },
            "update_callback" => function ($value, $user, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {

                update_user_meta($user->ID, $field_name, $value);

            },
        ]
    );


});
```